# Reference property from Firestore is always undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async.js

I have a query that outside the emulator is always returning a document reference property as `undefined`.

> UPDATE: The issue is happening when running from the browser.

Of course, I checked the document in the Firebase console and the record contains the value reference in the property `vendor`.

I'm getting different behaviours from the emulator/testing and from the browser, when executing the query. In the emulator and testing, it is working.

I have this converter:

```js
  private converter: FirestoreDataConverter<StockItem> = {
    toFirestore: (stockItem) => {
      const data = {...stockItem};
      data.vendor = this.vendorDAO.docRef(stockItem.vendor);
      return data;
    },
    fromFirestore: async (snapshot, options) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      console.log(data); // This contains the vendor property always as undefined.
      data.vendor = await this.vendorDAO.retrieve(data.vendor.id)
      return StockItem.fromJSONWithId({...data}, snapshot.id)
    }
  }
```

And I'm using it for a query:

```js
    const stockSnapshot = await getDocs(stockQuery);
    const retrievingData = stockSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

If execute it in the emulator, all is fine, but running with a real collection, the `snapshot.data()` object returned in the `fromFirestore` function always has the `vendor` reference object as `undefined`.

```js
{
price: 13
quantity: 3
vendor: undefined
}
```

Versions:
`"firebase": "^9.19.1"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to delete the question because, even when the error is not related to Firestore, it is related with async.

The main problem was a typo in the name of the collection, but the code was printing data after updating the `data` object, so looks like it's Firestore the want returning `undefined`

I mean, in this code:

```js
      console.log(data); // This contains the vendor property always as undefined.
      data.vendor = await this.vendorDAO.retrieve(data.vendor.id)
```

**no idea why**, but the `console.log` was printing the data content after the `data.vendor` was assigned to `undefined` because the config error in the `vendorDAO`.

Why this behaviour in the browser and why not happening from unit testing?